# Storing & getting the device orientation (yaw, pitch, roll) when taking a photo

Tags: camera, sensors

I want to take a photo and use the stored GPS coordinates and the orientation of the phone to do some calculations. How can I access that information?

Alternatively if there is an API to do that I could make my own app.

Comment: Android provides [Sensors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html) API if you want to create yourself an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course! You can use [Metadata viewer](http://download.cnet.com/EXIF-Viewer/3000-2193_4-75912951.html)  to see the GPS coordinates and other information of your photos.
Android has  Handful of APIs for anything you want. If you a developer you can make use of that.
Here is all you need.

- [Tutorial to get yaw, pitch, roll in android.](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/accelerometer/get_accelerometer_readings/)
- [Simple Camera API tutorial](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-camera-tutorial)
- [Google documentation about accelerometer api](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html)
  :)

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those problems that I believe requires a documented standard:  the same reason every platform trivially accesses the GPS location of a photo is because of EXIF and it's standardized tags.

EXIF is not user-extensible, and side car files are too namespace-y (proprietary).

Unless I'm wrong about there not being a standard place for Euler angles or even the quaternion that establishes device attitude.

Comment: After WWDC 2017, ARKit mostly addresses this for iOS.